# Kubernetes and storageclass gluster heketi

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs

I am try setup StorageClass and PersistanceVolumeClaim in Kubernetes and right now I have problem that's not working.

what I have:

**glusterfs-sc.yaml**

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: gluster-heketi
provisioner: kubernetes.io/glusterfs
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
allowVolumeExpansion: true
parameters:
  resturl: "http://server_ip:8080"
  restuser: "admin"
  restuserkey: "key"
  volumetype: "replicate:3"
  volumenameprefix: "vol"
  clusterid: "cluster_id"
```

**glusterfs-pvc.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
 name: gluster-pvc
spec:
 storageClassName: gluster-heketi
 accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
 resources:
   requests:
     storage: 1Gi
```

**pod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gluster-pod
  labels:
    name: gluster-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: gluster-pod
    image: busybox
    command: ["sleep", "60000"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: gluster-vol
      mountPath: /usr/share/busybox
      readOnly: false
  volumes:
  - name: gluster-vol
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: gluster-pvc
```

And PersistentVolumeClaim is still *pending* and pod show me message *'0/5 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/5 nodes are available: 5 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..'*

I am looking to this tutorial https://computingforgeeks.com/configure-kubernetes-dynamic-volume-provisioning-with-heketi-glusterfs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: glusterfs-cluster
  labels:
    storage.k8s.io/name: glusterfs
    storage.k8s.io/part-of: kubernetes-complete-reference
    storage.k8s.io/created-by: ssbostan
subsets:
 - addresses:
  - ip: ipserver
ports:
  - port: port_number
```

and after this..

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: glusterfs-volume
  labels:
    storage.k8s.io/name: glusterfs
    storage.k8s.io/part-of: kubernetes-complete-reference
    storage.k8s.io/created-by: ssbostan
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    - ReadOnlyMany
    - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: ""
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  glusterfs:
    endpoints: glusterfs-cluster
    path: k8s-volume
    readOnly: no
```